# AVG Error (reinstall ubuntu)

Tags: apt, dpkg, reinstall

I get some problems with Ubuntu... And I need to reinstall he..

I can't enter in Ubuntu, I only can enter in full terminal.

I try reinstall with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

And I get:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
avg2012lms
```

I try very commands like: `sudo dpkg -R -P avg2012lms` ; `sudo apt-get remove --purge avg2012lms`

Nothing works, I try to kill `avg` process.

Someone can help please?

Comment: Another thing
i can't install nothing he just make: "Errors were encountered while processing: avg2012lms"

Comment: How have you installed avg2012lms? as deb? from here http://www.avg.com/eu-en/download-2012.prd-alb

Comment: Yes i installed in http://www.avg.com/eu-en/download-2012.prd-alb

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy avg2012lms`, the output of `find /opt -type d -iname '*avg*'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the full error message and you gave us only two lines (bold in the message below)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  avg2012lms*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 157 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 515099 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing avg2012lms (2012.1795) ...
Failed to stop avgd.service: Unit avgd.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript avgd, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package avg2012lms (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 avg2012lms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

A similar error might see when you install the package. In other words, the whole thing was not running.

---

*Therefore*

Open the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/avg2012lms.prerm`

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/avg2012lms.prerm
```

and replace this

```
case "$1" in

    remove|deconfigure|upgrade)

       if which invoke-rc.d >/dev/null 2>&1; then
           invoke-rc.d avgd stop
       else
           /etc/init.d/avgd stop
       fi
```

with this

```
case "$1" in

    remove|deconfigure|upgrade)

#       if which invoke-rc.d >/dev/null 2>&1; then
#           invoke-rc.d avgd stop
#       else
#           /etc/init.d/avgd stop
#       fi
```

and now again

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge avg2012lms
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Finally you should search running `avgd` processes and kill them.

Comment: Only 1 question where i save?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment.

Comment: When i replace, i need to save the file he say to make: ^O ... But not work xD

Comment: use `sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/info/avg2012lms.prerm` as I said in my answer. You can save the file only as root.

Comment: Sorry its my first time using ubuntu... I do not understand how to make this... Can you help me?

Comment: Open a terminal and start `sudo -i gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/avg2012lms.prerm`. Make the changes and save. Then follow the next steps in my answer. `sudo apt-get remove --purge avg2012lms` and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: "Open a terminal and start sudo -i gedit /var/lib/dpkg/info/avg2012lms.prerm. Make the changes and save"
Yes but how to save? xD

Comment: Ctrl-S or via the menu

Comment: I think i accepted xD